# Are constellations "artificial kinds"?

Tags: naturalism

> To say that a kind is natural, rather than artificial or arbitrary,
> means, minimally, that it reflects some relevant aspects of the world
> and not only the interests of, or facts about, the classifiers. The
> expression “footwear under $100,” for instance, describes an
> artificial kind reflecting some categorizer’s interest—their
> budget—and not some relevant feature of the classified objects.

https://iep.utm.edu/nat-kind/

Are constellations "artificial kinds"? They are definitely ways of carving up the world: but does that occur "at the joints"?

If not, then does that mean a constellation depends on subjects in order to exist?

Comment: A constellation is an example of a *form*, and form is the product of minds.  Without minds, there are no constellations.  What we here on earth call a constellation is clearly dependent on facts about our location.

Comment: @nwr, not only our location in the cosmos, but the orientation of our planet, our visual apparatus, and our experiences of the world.

Comment: Yes, arranging stars into dippers and bows definitely does not cut nature at the joints, and depends on subjects familiar with what dippers and bows look like.

Comment: ha @Conifold how un-pagan  of you.